# N'Șc' considered duplicate key of N'C' using Latin1_General_CI_AS collation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, collation, unique-constraint

I have a table with a unique key that includes an `NVARCHAR(50)` column (correct or not, but is there). So, when trying to insert `Șc` or `C` (doesn't matter the order of the insert) it breaks on the 2nd insert due to collation issues. Here is the error:

> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 16
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.testT' with unique index 'IX_TestT'. The duplicate key value is (C).

Select returns:

[image]

Database default collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Spent some time looking on how to solve it, without changing too much the already existing structure, but can't find a way to getting working. Tried different collations and combinations, everything fails. Read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22409462/1297603) and [here](https://www.olcot.co.uk/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/)) about character expansions and so on, still stuck. Here is a sample code that I'm using to replicate the issue, feel free to modify and recommend anything that could help solve this.

```
CREATE TABLE testT (
    [Default_Collation]     [NVARCHAR] (50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
    [Latin1_General_CI_AS]  [NVARCHAR] (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    [Latin1_General_CI_AI]  [NVARCHAR] (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
    [SQL_Collation]         [NVARCHAR] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TestT] ON [dbo].[testT] ([Default_Collation])
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO testT
SELECT  N'Șc',  --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        N'Șc',  --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        N'Șc',  --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        N'Șc'   --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

INSERT INTO testT
SELECT  N'C'    --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
        ,N'C'   --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        ,N'C'   --COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        ,N'C'   --COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

SELECT * FROM testT;

DROP TABLE testT;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the old SQL Server Collations (i.e. those with names starting with `SQL_`) and the first two versions of the Windows Collations (the `80` series which came with SQL Server 2000 and do not have a version number in the name, and the `90` series which came with SQL Server 2005) are missing the sort weights for a great many characters. This was mostly corrected starting with the `100` series Collations that came with SQL Server 2008.

As you can see in the below examples, the `Ș` character matches an empty string when using non-binary, version 80 or 90 Collations (and SQL Server Collations) since they both have the same sort weight: 0. Nothing. Nada. This means that when comparing `N'Șc'` with `N'C'` (using pre-series 100 Collations), you are really comparing `N'c'` with `N'C'` (test #1):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE N'Șc' = N'C' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
-- no result (due to "c" and "C" being different case)

SELECT 2 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
SELECT 3 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;

SELECT 4 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2;
-- no result (due to "Ș" still being a code point and empty string has no code points)

SELECT 5 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS;
-- no result (due to "Ș" finally having a sort weight in 100 series Collations)

SELECT 6 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AI;
SELECT 7 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Chinese_PRC_90_CI_AI;

SELECT 8 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Indic_General_90_CI_AI;
SELECT 9 WHERE N'Ș' = N'' COLLATE Indic_General_100_CI_AI;
-- no result (due to "Ș" finally having a sort weight in 100 series Collations)
```

So, unfortunately you will need to drop the PK, alter the column to have a 100-level Collation (e.g. `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`), and then recreate the PK. Please note that the difference in that suggested Collation from the current Collation is both the `100` *and* the `_SC` at the end, which allows it to properly handle supplementary characters.

This does *not* mean that you need to:

1. change the Collations of other tables (unless they have the same setup of `NVARCHAR` in the PK)
2. change the Database's default Collation. The main issue with not changing the DB's Collation is that there will be a behavior difference between doing `table.column = N'Ș'` and `@variable = N'Ș'` since variables and string literals use the Database's default Collation.

For more examples of this behavior, please see the "Supplementary Characters" section of the following blog post of mine:

[The Uni-Code: The Search for the True List of Valid Characters for T-SQL Identifiers, Part 3 of 2 (Delimited Identifiers)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/04/16/the-uni-code-the-search-for-the-true-list-of-valid-characters-for-t-sql-identifiers-part-3-of-2-delimited-identifiers/)